# Why does my program print 0 instead of the calculated GCD?

Tags: c++

Hey I'm trying to calculate GCD (greatest common denominator) with cpp but my program is printing 0 instead of the GCD and there is no error!!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int emptyi;
    int number1;
    int number2;
    int counter1 = 0;
    int baghimandeh1 = 0;
    int liste1[100];
    int baghimandeh2 = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    int liste2[100];

    cout << "add your number: " << endl;
    cin >> number1;

    cout << "add your second number: " << endl;
    cin >> number2;

    for (int i = 1; i <= number1; i++) {
        if (number1%i == 0) {
            baghimandeh1 = number1;
            liste1[counter1] = i;
        }
        counter1++;
        // baghimandeh1 = number1 %i ;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= number2; i++) {
        if (number1%i == 0)
            baghimandeh2 = number2;
        liste2[counter2] = i;
    }
    counter2++;

    // baghimandeh2 = number2 %i ;

    for (int i = 0; i <= counter1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= counter2; j++) {
            if (liste1[i] == liste2[j]) {
                emptyi = liste1[i];
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "b,m,m  shoma hast: " << emptyi;
}
```

I wanna calculate Denominator of each user's input and then print the biggest among them and it will be GCD but it print's 0 no matter what number I enter.

Comment: Your initial indentation made the code really confusing because you had a closing brace for the if on the end of the line (which is rarely done ime) but worse the next line had the same indentation even though it wasnt part of the if block.

Comment: Don't know if this is the problem, but in that second loop, `liste2[counter2] = i;` stuffs all the `i` values into `liste2[0]`.

Comment: Also counter2 is incremented only once (after the loop, so basically by the time you reach that final loop its guaranteed to be 1, which seems... suspicious.

Comment: FYI @alireza, I never, ever, attempt to understand poorly formatted code.  I just move on.  So, you might find [this site](https://codebeautify.org/cpp-formatter-beautifier) of interest (and there are others).

Comment: I'm guessing that the first two for loops are supposed to be doing the same thing with two different data sets. That cries out to be a separate function rather than copying the same code into two places.

Comment: @PeteBecker would have avoided what seems to be a copy paste error, `if (number1%i == 0)` this is in both loops so were checking the denominators for number1 twice.

Comment: Problem #1: You arrays aren't initialized completely, you only write some of the elements the rest have unknown values (which is a problem because the final loops reads all of them). So first you need to ` = { 0 };` on liste1 and liste2. Secondly, I believe the condition for the final loop should be `if (liste1[i] == liste2[j] && liste1[i] != 0) {` why? because again you didn't write all the elements, so you dont want to compare those for equality. Alternatively, only increment the counter if you write something.

Comment: Problem #3 your final loop iteration shoud be using < not <=

Comment: @Borgleader -- the arrays don't need to be initialized. That's the point of `counter1` and `counter2` -- they keep track of the high-water mark in each array, so, used correctly (as you say, `<` and not `<=`) only the values that were assigned in the earlier loops are accessed.

Comment: @PeteBecker No because theyre incremented outside of the if, only if %i == 0 is the array written (in the if) counter is incremented *all the time*

Comment: use `std::vector<int> liste1, liste2;` and `liste2.push_back(i);` in the loop.

Comment: Instead of the double loop at the end you can remove the larger number (`liste1.back()` or `liste2.back()`) from liste1 or liste2 until they are equal. That is your GCM then. Or use an iterator.

Comment: @Borgleader -- well, yes, if you read the clearly incorrect code in the question. Fixing the bugs in the code would mean that the arrays don't need to be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I'll point out some errors I've seen:

- `counter1` and `counter2` should be updated **only** when the `if` clauses are true.
- The block below always executes the last line; I understand this is a bug you introduced when debugging.
- Also in that block, you use `number1` instead of `number2`.

```cpp
if (number1%i == 0)
    baghimandeh2 = number2;
liste2[counter2] = i;
```

Apart from those errors:

- The algorithm only works with input numbers with no more than 100 divisors.
- Some variables are not initialized.
- The last double `for` loop is very inefficient.
- It would be preferable not to `using namespace std;`

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ks85a79vT) of your code with some fixes and some debug info added.

---

The algorithm could be much simpler though; a bit more efficient and without needing to use any array. For example, given two positive numbers, get the mininum of them, and walk an index from that minimum towards `1`, until both numbers are divisible by the index.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/4o1q3KssT)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // min
#include <iostream>  // cin, cout

int main() {
    int number1{};
    std::cout << "add your number:\n";
    std::cin >> number1;

    int number2{};
    std::cout << "add your second number:\n";
    std::cin >> number2;

    auto min_counters{std::min(number1, number2)};

    int emptyi{};
    for (int i = min_counters; i >= 1; --i) {
        if (number1 % i == 0 and number2 % i == 0) {
            emptyi = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "b,m,m shoma hast: " << emptyi;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int number1;
    int number2;
    std::vector<int> liste1, liste2;

    std::cout << "add your number: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> number1;

    std::cout << "add your second number: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> number2;

    for (int i = 1; i <= number1; i++) {
        if (number1 % i == 0) liste1.push_back(i);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= number2; i++) {
        if (number2 % i == 0) liste2.push_back(i);
    }

    auto d1 = liste1.rbegin();
    auto d2 = liste2.rbegin();
    while(true) {
        if (*d1 == *d2) {
            std::cout << "GDC(" << number1 << ", " << number2 << ") = " << *d1 << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        if (*d1 > *d2) {
            ++d1;
        } else {
            ++d2;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: testing all integers for number2 is inefficient. You only need to test those numbers that are a denominator for number1, i.e. everything in liste1. So just iterate backwards over liste1 till you find a number that is a denominator for number2.